# Template class forward declaration

Tags: c++, templates, forward-declaration

I am forward declaring a template outer and inner class as follows

```
template<class T>
class outer;

class inner;
```

Just after the above declaration I have a `boost::serialization` declaration defined as

```
namespace boost
{
    namespace serialization
    {
         template<class Archive> 
         void serialize(Archive &ar, outer &var, ...) { }
    }

}
```

Outer is a template class and thus requires specification of template arguments.  If I attempt to do so as follows

```
...
     void serialize(... outer<T> &var ... ) { }
...
```

this is an error as only one template declaration is allowed.  What is the proper way to define such a forward declaration?

Comment: If im not wrong you should do: template<class Archive> template<class T> void serialize(Archive &ar, outer<T> &var, ...) { }. i dont remember but i think you can also put the templates in one line: template<class Archive, class T>

Comment: Why can't you use template<class Archive, class T> ?

Comment: @tomislav-maric I thought I needed to separate template declarations; I thought they were unique and should not be mixed.  I will do what you are suggesting.  Put up an answer and I will up-vote and mark.

Comment: @Mushy thanks for waiting, I answered.. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using two template parameters:

```
namespace boost
{
    namespace serialization
    {
         template<class Archive, class T> 
         void serialize(Archive &ar, outer<T>& var, ...) { }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I might have misunderstood, but can you not do this:

```
template <class Archive, typename T>
void serialize( Archive archive, out<T> &var, ... );
```